# Issue with HMTL5 Desktop Notifications in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications

I'm having problems adding basic desktop notifications to my wicket site.  Based on the example code at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification I've overridden the renderHead(IHeaderResponse) method in my page so that the following is added to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="desktopNotification-init">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
  function notifyMe(){ 
    if (!("Notification" in window)) { 
      alert("This browser does not support desktop notification"); 
    }else if (Notification.permission === "granted") { 
      var notification = new Notification("You have a system notification"); 
    }else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') { 
      Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) { 
        if(!('permission' in Notification)) { 
          Notification.permission = permission; 
        } 
        if (permission === "granted") { 
          var notification = new Notification("You have a system notification"); 
        } 
     }); 
    } 
  }

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

I then have a button that adds a call to the function when clicked:

```
public void onClick( AjaxRequestTarget p_target, WebMarkupContainer p_menuItemComponent ) {
    if( p_target != null  ) {
      p_target.appendJavaScript( "notifyMe();" );
    }
}
```

This works in Firefox but clicking the button has no effect in Chrome.  It seems to be an issue with the permission request as it works correctly if I change settings to always allow notifications.  Is there an issue with the javascript that I'm missing?